# warning mktime() expects parameter 4 to be long string

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

```
  warning mktime() expects parameter 4 to be long string
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to store Date of birth into a mysql database.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    #container{
    width:350px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#82ABEA;
    }
    label{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    fieldset{
    border-color:#82ABEA;
    }
    button{
    background-color:#900;
    color:#FFF;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <form method="post" action="save_reg.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><b>Register Here</b></legend>


    <label>Date Of Birth</label>
    <select name="db">
    <option selected>Month</option>
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>

    </select>
    <select name="dbd">
    <option selected>Day</option>
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>04</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>06</option>
    <option>07</option>
    <option>08</option>
    <option>09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    </select>

    <select name="dby">
    <option selected>Year</option>
    <option>2005</option>
    <option>2006</option>
    <option>2007</option>
    <option>2008</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2013</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2015</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <button><b>Submit</b></button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**And here is The Php code I have used:**

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "", "register");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo"Connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}else{
echo "Connection Succesfull";
}

$db= $_POST['db'];
$dbd= $_POST['dbd'];
$dby= $_POST['dby'];

$date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$db, $dbd, $dby));

$sql = "INSERT INTO register_form(dateb) VALUES('$date')";

if(!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
echo"Data is not saved";
}else{
echo $_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'] . "your data is saved";
}
```

**Can someone please guide me to add date of birth to the database?**

Comment: db is a string eg September and thats why it wont parse it.

Comment: can you explain me bit because i have just started programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to input months as their numerical representation, you need the dropdown values of months like this:

```
<option disabled selected>Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
```

So that when you use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), it will be the correct parameter to the months.

> int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, **`int $month = date("n")`** [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )

Look at the `month` parameter. It needs the format `date('n')` which equivalents to:

> Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros

Obligatory note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: i want to export my fetched data(which is fetched on the page) from database to a pdf format or excell format, can you guide me in this

Comment: @sandeepSK thats too broad, anyway you can select those values first, and then maybe use `fpdf` or `tcpdf`

Answer (score 0):

Your drop down options for db should have numeric values.